# How to use an unnamed type implementing a trait in a closure's return type?

Tags: rust

Closures are unnamed types in rust, so you have to use `impl Fn` to return one. Is it possible to also use an unnamed type for the closure's return type?

This is what I'm trying to do:

```rust
use actix_web::{services, web, Resource, dev::HttpServiceFactory};

pub fn service_factory() -> impl Fn() -> (impl HttpServiceFactory + 'static) + Clone + Send + 'static {
    || services![web::resource("/a"), web::resource("/b")]
}
```

But the compiler disallows `(impl HttpServiceFactory + 'static)` and tells me that `impl Trait` is only usable in function return values, so I'm instead forced to do this:

```rust
use actix_web::{services, web, Resource};

pub fn service_factory() -> impl Fn() -> (Resource, Resource) + Clone + Send + 'static {
    || services![web::resource("/a"), web::resource("/b")]
}
```

which works, but is a pain to use; also, if the type I'm returning from the closure was truly unnamed (such as another closure), this workaround wouldn't be possible at all.

What's the idiomatic way to write this code?

I should also mention that `Box<dyn HttpServiceFactory + 'static>` doesn't work for me because some function somewhere doesn't expect boxed trait objects, so the type has to be known.

Comment: Can't find `HttpContextFactory`. Please provide a [MRE].

Comment: Can you use nightly?

Comment: @Finomnis `HttpContextFactory` is a trait in `actix_web`. The first sample doesn't compile anyway, and the samples are only meant as an example, the question isn't about them. But sure, I can add that extra `use` statement. EDIT: ah, you're right. It's `HttpServiceFactory`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman unfortunately, no.

Comment: *"samples are only meant as an example, the question isn't about them"* - then please in future provide examples that are syntactically correct, complete, and actually represent the question.

Comment: @Finomnis I'd say the question was comprehensible enough, given that it was answered before I edited it. I'm starting to see why some people say SO has a toxic community.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, this wasn't meant as a mean comment :) I simply tried to point out why you might not get an answer. It's much easier to answer a question if you can copy out some code that represents it and play around with it. Otherwise people that answer it have to write said code themselves, which is tedious and frustrating if you answer a large amount of questions per day.

Comment: While there are toxic people on SO (which I apologize for), I think most people just perceive it as toxic because they misinterpret straightforward messages without much formalities as mean or condescending. In reality, you have to realize that the people who write the answers most often have limited time and are tech people, which tend to focus more on the content of a sentence than the formalities. I apoligize if that comes across rude sometimes; it's definitely not meant as such.

Comment: Further, you have to realize that not everyone here is American. Actually, most of the people here aren't. And other countries might have a different "niceness" or "politeness" in their culture. Americans are known for incorporating a lot of politeness in their sentences; Germans for example usually regard those nicenesses as pointless phrases that bear no meaning and are annoying to listen to because you have to actively ignore them. Again, I apologize if that's how it came across, but in most cases on SO it's not meant in a mean way, it's more of a tech/other countries culture difference.

Comment: @Finomnis sorry to make you go out of your way to explain all of this. I failed to make myself clear. I said "some people say SO is toxic", I didn't mean I find it toxic personally. Also, I'm not American, though many people seem to think so lately XD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make a helper trait "alias" with an associated type:

```rust
trait HttpContextFactoryFn: Fn() -> Self::Factory {
    type Factory: HttpContextFactory + 'static;
}

impl<F, T> HttpContextFactoryFn for F
where
    F: ?Sized + Fn() -> T,
    T: HttpContextFactory + 'static,
{
    type Factory = T;
}
```

This trait is equvialent to `Fn() -> (impl HttpContextFactory + 'static)`, except it's one that can actually be expressed in Rust today. That means that you can use this in your function signature:

```rust
pub fn service_factory() -> impl HttpContextFactoryFn + Clone + Send + 'static {
    || services![web::resource("/a"), web::resource("/b")]
}
```